# Merge Datasets based on 3 columns with not the same size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I want to merge two datasets but i don't know how. The first dataset have the following format.

```
  Year    Team    Wins   Loses
  ----------------------------
  2020    MLK     14       4
  2020    BRKL    10       5
  2020    PHX      5      10
  2019    BRKL    11       4
  2019    MLK     10       5
  2019    PHX      8       7
  2018    ...     ...     ...
```

The second dataset has the following format:

```
  Year    Team1  Points1  Team2   Points2
  ---------------------------------------
  2020    MLK      80      PHX      66
  2020    PHX      71      BRKL     70
  2020    BRKL     90      MLK      80
  2019    PHX      69      BRKL     70
  2019    ...      ...     ...      ...
```

The final dataset i want to have the following format:

```
  Year    Team1  Points1  Team2   Points2 Team1Wins Team1Loses  Team2Wins  Team2Loses
  2020    MLK      80      PHX      66       14         4           5          10 
  2020    PHX      71      BRKL     70       5          10          10          5
  2020    BRKL     90      MLK      80       10         5           14          4
  2019    PHX      69      BRKL     70       8          7           11          4
  2019    ...      ...     ...      ...      ...        ...         ...         ...
```

I have read questions here but i don't have find a solution for my problem. I have tried something like above but it is not the right solution.

```
  import pandas as pd

  a = pd.read_csv("Score.csv",error_bad_lines=False)
  b = pd.read_csv("Team.csv",error_bad_lines=False)
  merged = pd.merge(a, b, how='left', on=['Year'])
  print(merged)
```

Is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: if you refer to my code i don't know. This is why i am making this question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `rename` columns:

```
d = {'WIN%':'Team1Wins','FG%':'Team1Loses','Team':'Team1'}
df = b.merge(a.rename(columns = d)[['Team1Wins','Team1Loses','Team1','Year']], 
             on=['Year', 'Team1'])

d = {'WIN%':'Team2Wins','FG%':'Team2Loses','Team':'Team2'}
df = df.merge(a.rename(columns = d)[['Team2Wins','Team2Loses','Team2','Year']], 
              on=['Year', 'Team2'])
print (df)
   Year Team1  Points1 Team2  Points2  Team1Wins  Team1Loses  Team2Wins  \
0  2020   MLK       80   PHX       66         14           4          5   
1  2020   PHX       71  BRKL       70          5          10         10   
2  2020  BRKL       90   MLK       80         10           5         14   
3  2019   PHX       69  BRKL       70          8           7         11   

   Team2Loses  
0          10  
1           5  
2           4  
3           4
```

Comment: Thanks you for your time, i have a Traceback (most recent call last) error in this line       df = b.merge(a.rename(columns = d), on=['Year', 'Team1'])

Comment: @The_elevator - Can you post last line of error?

Comment: This is the last line of error: 
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1684, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'Team1'

Comment: @The_elevator - So it means there is no column name `Team1`, what is `print (df1.columns.tolist())` and  `print (df2.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: i run the following commands like this print (a.columns.tolist()) and this print me in my screen this: ['Year', 'Team1', 'Points1', 'Team2', 'Points2']

Comment: Super, and for `a` ?

Comment: for the other dataset because i have more columns that i have write in the question is this: ['Year', 'Team', 'GP', 'WIN%', 'PTS', 'FGA', 'FG%', '3PA', '3P%', 'FTA', 'FT%', 'REB', 'AST', 'TOV', 'STL', 'BLK', 'BLKA', 'PF', '+/-'] I adjust this  line to my needs d = {'Wins':'Team1Wins','Loses':'Team1Loses','Team':'Team1'}

Comment: @The_elevator - Answer was edited - if need `WIN%` instead `Wins` and `FG%` instead `Lost` columns